# How to call built-in twig function from custom twig filter?

Tags: php, symfony, twig, twig-extension

I want to create a custom filter which will return HTML link to client profile.

I need something like:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Twig;

use App\Entity\Client;
use Twig\Environment;
use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;
use Twig\TwigFilter;

class ClientExtension extends AbstractExtension
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getFilters(): array
    {
        return [
            new TwigFilter('client_link', [$this, 'createClientLink'], [
                'is_safe' => ['html'],
                'needs_environment' => true,
            ]),
        ];
    }

    public function createClientLink(Environment $environment, Client $client): string
    {
        // this code is an example, such function does not exist
        $url = $environment->callTwigFunction('path', 'client_profile', [$client->getId()]);
        return '<a href="'.$url.'">'.$client->getEmail().'</a>';
    }
}
```

What I cannot figure out is how do I call the `path` twig function? Is there some `callTwigFunction`-like feature I can use?

Comment: Not really.  What you have to do is to find out which extension implements the function in question then call that extension.  In many cases the actual functions are not defined within the extension itself which generally makes it easier to call the function directly.

Comment: Thanks @Cerad, I figured it out :)

Comment: Use the [UrlGeneratorInterface](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#generating-urls-in-services). This is what the Symfony Twig Bridge is doing [here for path](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/6.1/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Extension/RoutingExtension.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented it this way:

```php
$url = $environment->getExtension(Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\RoutingExtension\RoutingExtension::class)->getPath('cp_client_show_summary', ['id' => $client->getId()]);
```

Thanks to the suggestion of @Cerad

**EDIT:**

I am going to keep the above code because it shows the answer to the more general question I had about "calling built-in twig functions from inside filters". However as pointed by others in the comments, the proper way for my case was to inject `UrlGeneratorInterface`:

```php
class AppExtension extends AbstractExtension
{
    public function __construct(
        private readonly UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator,
    ) {
    }

    //...
```

and then generate URL like this:

```php
$url = $this->urlGenerator->generate('cp_client_show_summary', ['id' => $client->getId()]);
```